# My relationship to the patient is that of: ____?

Tags: sentence-construction, colons

Say, a mother is filling out a form for her daughter (patient) at the hospital. Which one should she put down in the given space - *Mother* or *Daughter*? I am assuming either one of these must be the answer since there is a colon after the *of*. Also, does it have to be ***A*** mother to feel like the sentence is complete. Anyway, my mother actually wrote *"I am her mother"* and told me to calm down... and I did, but I could always ask here on StackExchange.

Comment: Filling out forms is not writing sentences. *Parent* or *mother* would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

This is why my first grade teacher taught me to answer questions with complete sentences.  Your mother's answer was a complete sentence, and resolved the ambiguity.

"I am her mother" is correct.

Based on the phrasing of the question in the title, "mother" would be the correct one-word answer.  The question is phrased in terms of "(I am the person filling out the form.)  My relationship to the patient is that (I am the patient's): ____".

The word "my" determines the implied subjects of the implied sentences and clauses.

If the patient were filling out the form, the correct one-word answer would be "self" or "me" or "myself".

Answer (score 0):

"My relationship to the patient is mother." If A is the mother of B, then the relationship of A to B is mother. If the mother was the patient and the child was filling out the form, then she would say "My relationship to the patient is daughter" or "child".